# Does the gcc compiler rule change or something else?

Tags: c++, gcc

I have been reading a book about compiler and linker. I got a snippet in the book:

```
#include <stdio.h>

namespace myname {
    int var = 42;
}

extern "C" double _ZN6myname3varE;

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", _ZN6myname3varE);
    return 0;
}
```

According to the book I think I can understand this snippet and the book tells that it will return **42**. The code the book gives to run the snippet is:

```
$ g++ ManaulNameMangling.cpp -o ManaulNameMangling
$ ./ManualNameMangling
42
```

But when I do the same thing on my Ubuntu I can not get **42**. It just returns a random number.

So I wonder what happens. Is the book wrong? Or maybe something is different between the compiler the book uses and mine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please give more context? Why do you(the book) think the output should be 42?

Comment: Why would you care? This is highly non-portable. It mixes types, uses reserved identifier, so just undefined.

Comment: Does it work if you declare the mangled variable as `int` rather than `double`? You're declaring it with the wrong type and passing the wrong type for the `%d` specifier, giving two flavours of undefined behaviour.

Comment: Not that much. I think the author means to give a sample about mangling. But unfortunately he gets the type wrong. Actually not wrong on his x86 but not suitable for x86_64.@vonbrand

Comment: Exercise in futility, what good can come of breaking type safety of C++?  I mean its is mostly idiot proof ...

Comment: @zhangyangyu, name mangling is an internal detail of the language implementation. That argument passing isn't always checked for variadic functions is unfortunate, but that is C for you. Sure, for some outlandish uses it is important to know what is going on, but don't feed it to newbies. Please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's what the book says, the book is wrong.

The standard answer: the code is invalid, you aren't allowed to declare variables whose names start with `_` (with some exceptions that do not apply here).

The system-specific answer: although `_ZN6myname3varE` is the mangled name (on your system) of `myname::var`, you do need to specify that it has the same type. `extern "C" double` and `int` don't match. Try `extern "C" int _ZN6myname3varE;` instead. If you get the type wrong, the compiler has no idea how to correctly pass the value to `printf`.

As noted in the comments, if the way `int` and `double` get passed to `printf` is sufficiently similar, there is a chance for the original code to work as intended, but that's not the case on your system. When compiling with GCC for x86-32 without any other special options, the original code gives the intended result.

Comment: Thanks! I changed `double` to `int` and then it do return **42**. I think the book has made a mistake. And also I won't write this kind of code.

Comment: The name mangling applied by different compilers can be different, and even (IIRC) was changed by GCC a while back.

Comment: The original nonsense *could* have worked as long as the compiler did't check `printf(3)` arguments, and memory layouts of `double` and `int` arguments are such that the call gets the right bit pattern...

Comment: @vonbrand About the name mangling: yes, but if the mangling on the OP's system is different, the OP would have got a linker error. About the `printf` call working: indeed, when compiling in 32-bit mode on my system, it does work. Will add a note.

Comment: Yes. I think the `printf` leads to the code doesn't run as expected on my PC. My PC is x86_64 and the author's is x86. I have tried and passing a double to `%d` will leads to a random number. @hvd

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify that x86_64 has "special" handling of floating point for `printf`.

Because x86_64 passes inputs in registers, even floating point. But Floating point registers are passed in SSE registers, integral types in regular registers. Since printf can't really know how many SSE registers were used, that is passed as a sesparate value in EAX (well, AL). Beyond what AL says, printf will pick values from the stack. [The reason for this odd way of passing values is that you can have 6 integer values in registers, and then, I think 6 SSE values. But printf may be called with any arbitrary number of integer and floating point arguments.]

If you mix double values with integer values and print them "in the wrong format", you will get values that are picked from "random" locations. In this particular case, it will take the value of the first integer register, and print that, since it's an integer format. Your value will have been passed as a `double` in an SSE register, and won't be "found" by printf.

In most architectures (definitely x86 and ARM), however, all variable arguments functions use only stack passing (or "one register type for everythng" in some rare cases). This means that no matter how messily you mix up the data types, the output will be correct if you pass the "right data", regardless of what type the processor thought it was.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation. Would you mind telling me that where can I learn such kind of knowledge?

Comment: The x86 calling conventions can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions ... As to me knowing this is pure fluke: I happened to be at the meeting of the x86_64 developers at SuSE when it was discussed.